How to use generic type as method parameter
I want to register multiple DbContexts in my application to try to make it more modular. However, many of the necessary calls are now duplicated, e.g.
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext1>((_, options) =>
    {
        // some configuration
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext2>((_, options) =>
    {
        // the exact same configuration
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    
    // and also
    
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    using var context1 =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext1>();
    context1.Database.Migrate();
    
    using var context2 =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext2>();
    context2.Database.Migrate();
    
    // etc.

The only thing different is the DbContext class, and this is true for the test setup, the migration, etc.
I'd love to have the option to be able to iterate over all the DbContexts each time, so it's less likely I'll forget to register one. Something like this:
public static void DoWithEachRegisteredDbContext(DoWithDbContext<> magic)
{
    magic<DbContext1>();
    magic<DbContext2>();
}

public delegate Type[] DoWithDbContext<TContext>();

// and this method is called like this for the above example

DoWithEachRegisteredDbContext(AddDbContext);

public Type[] AddDbContext<TContext>() {
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<TContext>((_, options) =>
    {
        // some configuration
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

DoWithEachRegisteredDbContext(Migrate);

public Type[] Migrate<TContext>() {
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    using var context =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}

I would like to use a design pattern or language feature to help me solve this conundrum, because reflection isn't worth it due to its maintenance costs.
Is something like this possible? How?

The question is unclear as it asks at least 4 different things. The answer to the 4th question is reuse the delegate, not the options object. What are you actually trying to do? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a table, connection or database model. A Unit-of-Work contains the entities needed for a specific business case, loads the objects needed for that case, tracks the changes  to those objects and then persists all of them at once when SaveChanges is called. to make it more modular is not a valid reason for multiple Unit-of-Work types.

@Panagiotis Kanavos
My example being a DbContext doesn't matter. It can also be a completely different type. What matters is that I want to use framework methods that are generically typed, and do not expect a Type object. (BTW, the ONE question is at the bottom. It's if there is a way to implement my example code.)

That's the one question you didn't ask at all. The actual question is how to construct a generic method call using Reflection. The optionsActino parameter isn't generic. This is answered in How do I call a generic method using a Type variable?

I don't understand the difference between these 2 examples. If you will forget one in the first example, you may also forget one in the second example. This issue should be avoided through unit testing.

@Panagiotis Kanavos I think you're responding to the wrong question. I never said anything about reflection, and in fact would love to have a proper solution for this.

The feature you're looking for is reflection. Finding the DbContext-derived types is a reflection feature. So is creating generic calls at runtime

@shingo I've added a second call to the DBContexts to make that clear. In the second example I only have to maintain DoWithEachRegisteredDbContext, while in the first I have to find the place where the DB context is added, the one were it's migrated, etc. and maintain all the context in all these individual classes.

At this point, where you stated you don't want to use reflection, it looks like the only solution is a source generator that finds all DbContext in the project/solution and generates the AddDbContext calls.

public Magic<T>() where T : DbContext { ... using var context =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>(); ... }

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking for, is to reduce redundant code, and Keep a method close to changes, yet open to extensions
There is a SOLID principle that is focused just around that, its called The Open Closed Principle (The "O" in SOLID) and it is a principle that helps us solving exactly these use-cases.
One way to solve it would be to use something like a dictionary, iterate through every DbContext in your instance and only add new contexts to that db,
However it doesn't sound like the most elegant solution.
I'd recommend diving into OCP and checking out what solutions it offers, as this is more of a problematic design choice, which can be solved really, in many different ways.
I would highly recommend learning SOLID better if you are not familiar enough with it.
Good luck! :)

A collection or dictionary of DbContexts doesn't work, because most methods surrounding the DB context do not accept a Type object, but are generically typed.

Sounds like its time to refactor
